# NAA flag pending for twenty hours after the post was deleted before being finally marked helpful

Tags: bug, flags, deleted-answers, specific-answer

Yesterday I raised an NAA flag on an answer ([link for >= 10k users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69508369/access-to-the-path-dev-shm-azurefunctions-is-denied-operation-not-permitted/69901349#69901349)), but noticed that at the same instant that I raised the flag, the answer was deleted.

On other occasions that this has happened, the NAA flag was marked helpful immediately (similar to if I'd cast the final spam or rude/abusive flag on a post that causes it to be deleted) - however on this occasion, as I was writing this answer, the flag (raised at 2021-11-09 16:21:06Z) was still pending - and had been for at least 20 hours:

> [image]

When I reloaded my flag summary I saw that the state of the NAA flag had changed from "pending" to "helpful". Accurate timestamps aren't displayed for when flags are handled, so I can only infer (based on the page being loaded at 12:33 UTC) that it was handled at around 12:27 UTC, i.e. around 20 hours after the post was deleted.

> [image]

I am only aware of four ways that an answer can be deleted (under normal circumstances):

1. The user saw it was being downvoted, and self-deleted it. This should cause the flag to be marked helpful ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/197964/284827)).
2. The answer was deleted from review. Clearly, this would cause the flag to be marked helpful.
3. The answer was deleted via delete votes. I'm not sure what would happen to (non-custom) flags in this case, but I would hope that they would be marked helpful.
4. A moderator deleted the answer. I'm not sure what would happen to flags in this case.

I can only assume that either a ♦ moderator deleted the post but didn't see my flag in time to handle it, or that there was some kind of race condition that caused the flag to be raised *after* the post was deleted - then somebody (presumably a ♦ moderator) handled the flag.

Can anybody shed any light on this?

Comment: @Suraj, from [the timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69901349/timeline), that answer was indeed deleted by the answerer themselves ~20 hours ago, then Zoe undeleted it and deleted it again ~50 minutes ago.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi ah. I stand corrected :). The answer was deleted by OP 20 hours ago. The Mod seems to have taken some action about 50 minutes ago.

Comment: This looks like a bug. You can't raise an NAA flag on a deleted post and when a post gets deleted NAA flag gets marked helpful automatically. Probably some race condition.

Comment: Probably a race condition, because the answer was OP-deleted in the same second you had cast your flag. I guess that is why your flag wasn't auto-approved, because such scripts ran before your flag was registered.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This seems to be a race condition.

According to the timeline, the post was deleted at 2021-11-09 16:21:06Z. Incidentally, it shows your flag as being raised on the same second as the post was deleted; 2021-11-09 16:21:06Z. However, the timeline shows your flag as being raised right after deletion:

> [image: image showing the flag appearing after the post was deleted]

I believe your flag was registered *right* after OP self-deleted the post, in a way that made the system think the flag was raised on a non-deleted post, but where the deletion processing had already wiped the other flags. This is speculation on my end, but the odds of triggering this bug are *extremely* low. Probably down to a few milliseconds here, where if it was a couple milliseconds off, you probably would've gotten an error or an instant flag approval instead.

**Correction:** We just had another instance of race condition flags on different seconds:

> [image: image showing another race condition on a different post]

There may still be milliseconds separating them, but two incidents in two days may indicate this is a new bug.

Comment: [Frédéric Hamidi](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/464709/fr%c3%a9d%c3%a9ric-hamidi) said [in the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412974/naa-flag-pending-for-twenty-hours-after-the-post-was-deleted-before-being-finall#comment878715_412974) that you undeleted then re-deleted the post - was that because you saw that this had happened in some way, or was that unrelated? I guess what I'm asking is: If you hadn't taken action, what would happen to the flag?

Comment: It was in part because I wondered how an NAA flag could be live on a deleted post, and in part because I figured I might as well mod delete it while I was at it.

Comment: Re: the edit, the flag showed up in the queue and could've been handled normally, but it would've been left in a limbo until a mod came along and handled it somehow. I.e. odds are the system wouldn't detect it being deleted, and clear the flag automatically.

Comment: Happens a lot actually. Easiest way is to just undelete and delete on the mod dash.

Comment: Does the SO API allow flagging deleted posts as NAA? It could allow it and in such case this is probably what happens. Otherwise yeah, some strange race condition.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli - I've never used the SO API - I flagged the post naturally.

Comment: In general, you can flag deleted posts for mod attention, but I doubt you can send an old NAA flag option through the API to a deleted post. Hence the high probability of a race condition.