# Why did this question accept four close votes instead of three?

Tags: support, bug, vote-to-close

I visited [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72249947/5320906) and elected to vote to close it as a general computing question.  As I clicked on the close link I noticed it read `Close (3)`<sup>*</sup>.  I clicked on the close link and was able to cast my close vote: the closure banner on the question displayed four close voters, me being the last, as does the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72249947/timeline).

[image]

There was a momentary site outage about 15 minutes earlier; I don't know if that's relevant.

---

<sup>*</sup> Users with [3000+ reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) see a "Close" link for voting to close followed by the number of already-cast close votes in parentheses.

Comment: [Recent events](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418080/i-upvoted-a-post-twice-actually-10-times) have shown the process for casting and processing votes are likely semi-separate. This also applies [to flags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/412975/6296561). Simply put, if the site died at just the right time, it wouldn't surprise me if the process in charge of actually closing the question was halted before it had a chance to do its thing, resulting in four votes to close. The downtime was likely caused by the recurring DDoS attacks, so this does seem like a plausible explanation

Comment: unfortunately, we're also  talking about timing around the range of milliseconds or below, so given SE's design approach to vote management and processing, as well as the fact that flag race conditions having been a thing for years (or so I've been told), I highly doubt this is fixable. It shouldn't really occur in the wild anyway, FWIW, but the "forced stress-tests" haven't exactly helped in keeping these bugs out of the wild

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine I thought the SO db was not distributed, so I don't see why the process of incrementing a close vote and if necessary closing a question would not be atomic.  But of course, there are always reasons why theory and practice might diverge :-(

Comment: I don't understand the logic here either. I'm also not privy to the details of how the system works (obviously; I'm a mod, not an employee), but my own observations seem to indicate the lack of atomic, and more importantly synchronized operations. like, when an answer is deleted while a flag is being cast, if it's registered after the process that clears any currently active flags, it's left on the post. Since a CM could clear the duplicate votes, that indicates an equivalent mismatch between the process of casting, and the process of dupe detecting and invalidating.

Comment: Equivalently, here, there's a mismatch between the process of casting a vote, and the process of actually closing the post. It's weird, and I don't understand the design well enough to explain why there's a mismatch. I may also be using the wrong terminology here, but again, this is just a best effort guess as to why casting a vote doesn't properly cast a vote, and atomically triggering side-effects, or why casting a flag that moments later is invalid for that post isn't better handled.

Comment: Well the synchronous event did happen because after the downtime three votes were cast and the question was closed, as expected. It is just that the one close vote that happened before the downtime is treated as if it did not happen with respect to the closure procedure. The signs of a complex system with many business rules.

Comment: Related on MSE: [Question had enough close votes to be closed, but was not closed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/359550/165261)